# How to make a Unity Editor member variable persistent? (member of Editor, NOT target class)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to use serializedObject.FindProperty() on a member of the target class, but I just want to make one of the Editor's member variables persistent. Googling onlyshows the cases for the target class.

```
    public class MyEditor: Editor
    {
        [SerializeField]
        int myInt = 1;
        ...
    } 
   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
      myInt = EditorGUILayout.IntField(myInt);
      ...
   }
```

I can set a value for myInt in the Inspector, but when I leave and then return to the Editor, myInt is reset to its default value. I know I could simply put myInt in the target class, but I need the variable in this class.

Comment: You can't. Editor classes are not serialized .. only the actual target. Your `[SerializeField]` has no effect whatsoever .. you only see the field due to `EditorGUILayout.IntField(myInt)` ...

Comment: `but I need the variable in this class.` .. why?

Comment: Thanks. For neatness - because it's a variable that can change the look and behaviour of the Editor Inspector, it has nothing to do with the function of the target class. But now you've explained that this isn't possible, I will indeed stick it in the target class.